# parse xml based on ordered List

Tags: java, xml, parsing, recursion, dom

I have a ordered list.

```
order, xml_parent, xml_field
1,Identification,Id
2,Identification.Name,LastName
3,Identification.Name,FirstName
4,Identification.OfficialAddress,StreetName
5,Identification.OfficialAddress,StreetNumber
7,Identification.OfficialAddress,PostalCode
8,Identification.OfficialAddress,City
9,Identification.OfficialAddress,Country
10,Identification.Nationality
13,ReasonIntroduction.AskSomething,FromDate
14,ReasonIntroduction.AskMore,FirstTime
```

which needs to be parsed to

```
<root>
    <Identification>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>
            <LastName>x</LastName>
            <FirstName>x</FirstName>
        </Name>
        <OfficialAddress>
            <StreetName>Fifth av.</StreetName>
            <StreetNumber>5</StreetNumber>
            <PostalCode>3212</PostalCode>
            <City>3212</City>
            <Country>UK</Country>
         </OfficialAddress>
         <Nationality>Qatar</Nationality>
    </Identification>
    <ReasonIntroduction>
        <AskSomething>true</AskSomething>
        <AskMore>true</AskMore>
    </ReasonIntroduction>
</root>
```

My file is not that huge so I'll be using java DOM parsing.

Instead of looping over this ordered list, I would like to use recursion to handle this but I do not get how I can get the "next" value.

So when treating "Identification.Name" for handling the "LastName" how do I get the "next" element "FirstName" which I do include under .

I'm pretty sure recursion is the right way but I'm missing some dots.

```
List<String> parentList = Arrays.asList(parentXmlName.split("\\.", -1));

Element parentElement = document.createElement(field.getXmlParentName());
Element element = document.createElement(field.getXmlName());
element.setTextContent(field.getValue());
parentElement.appendChild(element);
```

Comment: `split(".", -1)` —The `split` method expects a regular expression.  A period is a special character in a regular expression, unless escaped.

Comment: Your spec doesn't make sense or is incomplete. It's not possible to translate the given tabular data into XML as the source data doesn't provide the leaf values (1, x, Fifth av etc). The source format is also odd in other ways - the "xml_parent" field is actually providing a path and not a parent. The "order" field is not clear either. Seems like a contrived and not well-thought out spec.